# SendKeys() in Powershell prepending and appending unwanted "=" to given string

Tags: powershell, sendkeys

I am attempting to use SendKeys in Windows Powershell using a ComObject:

```
> $wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
> $wshell.SendKeys('Hello World')
```

I would expect this to 'print' "Hello World" into the input of my powershell terminal.

```
> Hello World
```

Instead, I get '=' around the string.

```
> =Hello World=
```

This behaviour is per-call of SendKeys(). Given a test script of 'Test.ps1':

```
#Test.ps1
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$wshell.SendKeys('a')
$wshell.SendKeys('')
$wshell.SendKeys('test')
```

I run it, and get:

```
> .\Test.ps1
> =a====test=
```

I am on Windows 10, version 10.0.19042. My Powershell version is as follows:

```
> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1320
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1320
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: on win10 with PoSh 5.1 console and pwsh 7.2.2 console ... i DO NOT get those prefix/postfix `=` chars.

Comment: Why are you using SendKeys in the first place?

Comment: I am looking into using SendKeys in Powershell as a possible method of automating various tasks in legacy windowed programs. Previously I've been using keyboard recording software but the programmable and reading-from-files aspects of a proper script seemed like it could fit my needs. This was an unexpected roadblock and I may choose to explore alternatives if this issue cannot be reproduced & fixed.

Comment: I would avoid the SendKeys method altogether. It is a legacy function that is likely to fail and/or be very difficult to troubleshoot depending on circumstances not in your control.